# Flutter coverage reporting in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, flutter

In the `Run` menu of Android Studio 3.3.1 the `Run ... with Coverage` is disabled:

[image]

Reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53221473/3356777) it seems it is now supported.

Is it true? What steps must be taken to enable the test with coverage?

Comment: Updated: my question arise because it seems someone make it works.