# show flutter test coverage

Tags: flutter, testing, dart, test-coverage

I am a bit new to testing world in flutter.
what I want to achieve is to determine my **test coverage** in flutter.

but I don't know any way to **determine my test coverage** ,
any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running the tests with

```
flutter test --coverage
```

should generate a file

```
/coverage/Icov.info
```

Which holds the information you need.

You can now extract infos from the file in various methods as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50789578/how-can-the-code-coverage-data-from-flutter-tests-be-displayed)

Comment: hi , is there any way to install ```lcov``` on windows ?

Comment: hi, I don't know, I'm not a Windows user :(

Comment: You can follow this link: https://txt.arboreus.com/2015/05/29/howto-get-lcov-test-coverage-on-windows.html

Answer (score 0):

In a easy way, you can determine the test coverage threshold using this package https://pub.dev/packages/dlcov

usage example:

`dlcov --lcov-gen="flutter test --coverage" --coverage=100`

`--lcov-gen` Generate the `lcov.info` file

`--coverage=100` To determine if the test coverage threshold is 100%