Flutter test SonarCloud
I would like to generate coverage.opencover.xml in flutter to use in SonarCloud
in CMD I run this:
D:\file\flutter_calculator>flutter test --coverage
00:06 +1: All tests passed!

I have Icov in coverage folder
but now I would like to convert this output to coverage.opencover.xml for SonarCloud
I tried this but does not work:
    D:\file\flutter_calculator>dart pub global activate coverage
Package coverage is currently active at version 1.7.2.
The package coverage is already activated at newest available version.
To recompile executables, first run `dart pub global deactivate coverage`.
Installed executables collect_coverage, format_coverage and test_with_coverage.
Warning: Pub installs executables into C:\Users\z004u3kh\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\bin, which is not on your path.
You can fix that by adding that directory to your system's "Path" environment variable.
A web search for "configure windows path" will show you how.
Activated coverage 1.7.2.

D:\file\flutter_calculator>dart pub global run coverage:format_coverage --lcov --in=coverage\lcov.info --out=coverage.opencover.xml --packages=./pubspec.yaml --report-on=lib
Unhandled exception:
FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1)
SF:lib\main.dart
^

#0      _ChunkedJsonParser.fail (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:1383:5)
#1      _ChunkedJsonParser.parseNumber (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:1250:9)
#2      _ChunkedJsonParser.parse (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:915:22)
#3      _parseJson (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:35:10)
#4      JsonDecoder.convert (dart:convert/json.dart:610:36)
#5      JsonCodec.decode (dart:convert/json.dart:216:41)
#6      HitMap.parseFiles (package:coverage/src/hitmap.dart:209:28)
#7      main (file:///C:/Users/z004u3kh/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/coverage-1.7.2/bin/format_coverage.dart:66:31)
#8      _delayEntrypointInvocation.<anonymous closure> (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:294:33)
#9      _RawReceivePort._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:189:12)

Icov
SF:lib\main.dart
DA:3,0
DA:4,0
DA:8,2
DA:11,1
DA:13,1
DA:15,1
DA:31,1
DA:40,1
DA:53,1
DA:54,1
DA:60,1
DA:61,2
DA:67,2
DA:71,1
DA:79,1
DA:80,1
DA:84,3
DA:87,3
DA:89,1
DA:92,1
DA:107,1
DA:111,1
DA:112,2
DA:113,3
DA:118,1
DA:119,1
LF:26
LH:24
end_of_record


https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50789578/how-can-the-code-coverage-data-from-flutter-tests-be-displayed

Hi Rafal, you can achieve this conversion using other tools. One such tool is the lcov_cobertura package, which converts lcov.info to Cobertura XML format, and then you can use another tool like ReportGenerator to convert Cobertura XML to OpenCover XML.
